# Inline action call that requires get_self() auth possible?

Tags: permissions

There is a contract B with an action 'create' which uses `require_auth( get_self() )`.
I would like to call that action from another contract A, is that even possible and if so - how?

Contract b has

```
CONTRACT B : public contract
{
   ACTION create() {
      require_auth( get_self() );
      printf("Hello");
   }
}
```

A noin-working implementation that channels the B account does not work

```
CONTRACT A : public contract
{
   ACTION do() {
     action (
         permission_level { "B"_n, "active"_n },
         "B"_n,
         "create"_n,
         std::make_tuple (
            ...
         )
     ).send();
   }
}
```

cleos

```
cleos push action A do '{}' -p B@active
```

Both A@active and B@active have eosio.code permission

> Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy
> declared authorizations Ensure that you have the related private keys
> inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked. Error Details:
> transaction declares authority '{"actor":"B","permission":"active"}',
> but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms,
> provided permissions [{"actor":"A","permission":"eosio.code"}],
> provided keys [], and a delay max limit of

Answer (score 1):

Any inline action from contract A is executed with A@eosio.code permission. `require_auth(get_self())` in contract B means it should be executed with B@active permission.

Your case can be resolved by adding A@eosio.code to B@active, but it means that inline actions from contract A can trigger any other actions with B@active permission. Unless you own both contract A and B, you shouldn't do that.

If A@eosio.code is added to A@active, you can check permission like:

```
eosio::check(has_auth(get_self()) || has_auth("A"_n), "missing required authority");
```